# Realm java chain queries for child

Tags: java, realm

Here's the sample parents with children

```
Parent[0].Children[0].Name = Johnson
Parent[0].Children[0].Age = 16

Parent[0].Children[1].Name = Jessica
Parent[0].Children[1].Age = 17

Parent[1].Children[0].Name = Lawson
Parent[1].Children[0].Age = 17

Parent[1].Children[1].Name = Jessica
Parent[1].Children[1].Age = 19
```

I just wanted to get parent with a child name Jessica & age 17

When I tried

```
realm.where(Parent.class).beginGroup().equalTo("childrens.name","Jessica").equalTo("childrens.age","17").endGroup().findAll();
```

It returned both parent to me as 2nd parent has children aged 17 & named Jessica. How can I get only the 1st parent?

Comment: Technically this is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406850/realm-query-by-two-params-in-list excluding kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a hacky way.

Create a unique key for child e.g.

```
Parent[0].Children[0].UniqueKey = name + "_" + age
```

and query the unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Link query means "has at least one of X where condition is true"

So your query

```
realm.where(Parent.class)  
     .beginGroup()
     .equalTo("childrens.name","Jessica")
     .equalTo("childrens.age","17")
     .endGroup()
     .findAll();
```

says,

"give me parents where parents has at least one of children where name is Jessica, AND has at least of one of children where age is 17"

Which is parent 1 and parent 2, because they both have a child named Jessica, and they both have a child aged 17.

---

You can do two things:

1.)

```
realm.where(Parent.class)  
     .equalTo("childrens.name","Jessica")
     .findAll()
     .where()
     .equalTo("childrens.age","17")
     .findAll();
```

2.) In Children, define `@LinkingObjects`

```
public class Child extends RealmObject {
    @LinkingObjects("children")
    private final RealmResults<Parent> parents = null;
}
```

And now you can do the check based on children:

```
RealmResults<Child> children = realm.where(Child.class).equalTo("name", "Jessica").equalTo("age", 17).findAll();
Child child = children.get(0);
RealmResults<Parent> parents = child.getParents(); // <-- parents of "Jessica, 17"
```

Comment: the first solution won't work in my case unfortunately. The 1st findAll returns both parents as both has child Jessica, then the 2nd findAll will also return both parents as both of them has child age 17. I will try the @LinkingObjects.